# Is there a fancier way to get a previous item with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table rows like so:

```
<tr class="parent0 row3" data-parent="0">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent3 row7" data-parent="3">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent3 row12" data-parent="3">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent0 row8" data-parent="0">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="parent0 row9" data-parent="0">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

So if I have a click handler:

```
$(document).on({
   "click": function(){
      var parentId = $(this).data("parent");
      //get previous sibling:
      //OPTION A:
      var prevParentA = 
              $(this).prev("parent" + parentId); //works sometimes
      //OPTION B:
      var prevParentB = 
              $(this).prevAll("parent" + parentId).eq(0); //works all the time but ugly...
   }

}, "tr");
```

**Option A** only works when the direct previous item has the same parent, but when that is **not** the case, `prevParentA === []` which is **not** the desired result.
**Option B** always seems to work, but it is **ugly** in that it is selecting **ALL** of the previous items matching that class and selecting the 1st one it finds.

Is there a better option than **Option B**?

Comment: @JosephSilber I am saying **without** using `prevAll`.... I know about that already...

Comment: @RobW -- The answer to that question selects even more elements than `prevAll` does!

Comment: @Vote-to-closers The question is not a duplicate. The linked questions are looking for previous elements, regardless of the position in the document tree. This question specifically looks for a method to select a previous element with a common parent.

Comment: @Esailija don't remove the duplicate links, just vote to reopen if you feel it is necessary :-)

Comment: I don't think they are duplicate at all.

Comment: @Esailija exactly. and they will be auto removed when the question is reopened :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery does not have something better than your option B.  I've long thought this was a missing piece of functionality as I've regularly wanted something like it too.  Fortunately, it's not too hard to make your own method:

```
jQuery.fn.prevFind = function(selector) {
    var elems = [];
    this.each(function(i, item) {
        while (item = item.previousSibling) {
            if (item.nodeType == 1) {
                if ($(item).is(selector)) {
                    elems.push(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return(this.pushStack(elems, "prevFind", selector));
}
```

The same could be done for a `nextFind()` also.

In your example, instead of this:

```
$(this).prevAll("parent" + parentId).eq(0);
```

you would use this:

```
$(this).prevFind("parent" + parentId)
```

---

And, here's an implementation of both `prevFind()` and `nextFind()` that uses some common code:

```
(function($) {

    $.each({
        'prevFind' : 'previousSibling',
        'nextFind' : 'nextSibling'
    }, function(method, dir) {

        $.fn[method] = function (selector) {

            var elems = [];

            this.each(function(i, item) {
                while (item = item[dir]) {
                    if (item.nodeType == 1) {
                        if ( $.find.matches(selector, [item]).length ) {
                            elems.push(item);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return this.pushStack(elems, method, selector);
        };
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDYDL/1/

Comment: Ok cool. So how could this be used? (I right now use both `prevAll` and `nextAll` all over....) Also does this method reduce the amount of items being selected?

Comment: Lols I just realised the while is already taking care of null ;d. Why was this downvoted :O

Comment: @Neal, yes this only traverses back until it finds a previous sibling that matches your selector.  `prevAll()` compares all previous siblings.  This does not do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hmmmm. I assume the check for `nextFind` is `this.nextSibling`?

Comment: @jfriend00 also what does `pushStack` do? I have never seen that used and the documentation on it is a bit confusing....

Comment: basically it allows you to use `.end` and `.andSelf`

Comment: @Esailija ok, so how do I use this new `prevFind(...)` function then?

Comment: @Neal Depending on your desired level of browser compatibility (majors and IE9+), you can also use [`.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling). Then, the `nodeType` check can also be left out.

Comment: `$(this).prevFind(".parent" + parentId)`

Comment: @Esailija and I _assume_ that will return the element that I want?

Comment: Yes, it will be equivalent to `.prevAll(selector).eq(0)` except more sophisiticated

Comment: @Esailija and for `nextFind` I would use `this.nextSibling`?

Comment: @Neal yes. And also the string at the end would be `"nextFind"`

Comment: it returns a new jQuery object of the found elements and links it with the current jQuery object so you can use `.end()` and `.andSelf()`

Comment: @Esailija why would I want to do that?

Comment: @Neal You usually don't because they are the usual warning sign of obnoxious chaining. But all the [jQuery traverse methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) use the jQuery stack so it's good to use it for consistency.

Comment: @Neal, I added an example usage for your situation.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks ^_^ you forgot the `return`s in your new example. I'll add them for you :-)

Comment: +1 for using `pushStack` and keeping the consistency of the jQuery API intact, even though most people don't appreciate it (till they try to use `end`, and bang their head against the wall).

Comment: Why is `dirFind ` pushed onto the jQuery prototype?

Comment: @jfriend00 ahhh this is getting stuck! the while loop continues forever!

Comment: @jfriend00 - I moved `dirFind` off the jQuery prototype, and combined the 2 function declarations into one.

Comment: @JosephSilber and Neal - thx for improving.  I've been off the grid for most of the day.  Improvements look good.  I made dirFind a method on its own because I thought there were other uses for it, but your method allows it to be reused too.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I realized that the second argument passed to `pushStack` was wrong. It was passing `previousSibling`/`nextSibling`, when it should be passing in the actual name of the function: `prevFind`/`nextFind`. I changed it, and I also added a fiddle. Hope you don't mind the fact that I refactored the code a bit.

Comment: @JosephSilber - the only thing I might change is I don't see why the self executing wrapper function is needed.  Just use `jQuery` instead of `$` in three places and the self executing function is not needed.  There are no variables in its scope that it's protecting.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Is the Sizzle interface a documented/committed part of jQuery.  I know it uses the Sizzle selector engine under the covers, but is it guaranteed to stay that way?  I guess I'm just wondering about the safety/longevity of using the Sizzle shortcut.

Comment: @jfriend00 - `$.find` has been [a direct link to Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js) since [about 3 years ago](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/81f65ce33931831dc651c5d3ebf2b31b551b6b8b/src/sizzle-jquery.js). `.matches` is just using the standard Sizzle interface.

Comment: @JosephSilber - that well may be, but is there any documentation on it or is it just an internal workings that is undocumented.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I couldn't find any official source, but [it's used all over the place](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+"%24.find"+sizzle). They'd be remiss to remove it at this point.

Comment: @JosephSilber - did you do some sort of performance test to justify using an undocumented interface?  I personally would stay with documented interfaces unless there was a compelling reason to rely on undocumented interfaces - especially when sharing code with others who are much less savvy than you.

Comment: @jfriend00 - jQuery is notorious for constantly making breaking changes - even in a point release - so I don't think sticking with the official API will guarantee you anything for the long run. I'd argue that `$.find` is as safe as it gets. [Here's a JSPerf showing that using Sizzle directly is over 100% faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-object-vs-sizzle-directly), so there is your justification (if ever it was needed). Having said all that, this is still your answer, so ultimately you've got the last word here. If you don't think it's justified, just roll it back. Sorry for meddling.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Yeah, but the documented APIs are certainly less likely to change without at least several versions of notice (as `.live()` illustrates) rather than just getting changed out from under you with no notification.  This whole scenario is just unusual for me.  You're editing my answer with the way you would do it, not the way I would do it.  I'd have no problem if it was your answer and how you want to do it - it's not the way I would do code that I was sharing with a large number of people.  There are very few cases where jQuery is absolutely the fastest way to do things.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I generally don't micro-optimize like this, but I feel that a traversal plugin has to be optimized to the fullest extent. Again, this is your answer, so if it doesn't fit your style, just roll back. Sorry.