# Multiple Toggles On The Same Page

Tags: javascript, toggle

So I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="full-width-red-left"></span>
<div class="full-width-red-wrapper">"Title
    <img src="/images/header_toggle_up.png" class="header-toggle" id="stafflist-icon" />
</div>
<span class="full-width-red-right"></span>
<div class="stafflist-content">
    <div class="full-width-content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="full-width-footer"></div>

<span class="full-width-red-left"></span>
<div class="full-width-red-wrapper">"Title
    <img src="/images/header_toggle_up.png" class="header-toggle" id="stafflist-icon" />
</div>
<span class="full-width-red-right"></span>
<div class="stafflist-content">
    <div class="full-width-content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="full-width-footer"></div>
```

And this is shown multiple times on the page, generated by a PHP foreach.

Then I have the following JS code I'm trying to get to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#stafflist-icon").toggle(function(){

       $(".stafflist-content").slideUp('slow');
    } , 

    function() { 
        $(".stafflist-content").slideDown('slow');
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Obviously with that code, if any #stafflist-icon is pressed, all the .stafflist-content DIVS slide up and down. What I need is when the #stafflist-icon is pressed, only the next .stafflist-content slides up or down and not every single one!

Is this possible without generating IDs for each one using a counter or something in the foreach?

Comment: I use toggles on a page I did few mounts ago... take a look at html and source code for menus. www.termoservis.hr

Comment: That's not multiple instances of it on one page though? If it was a single toggle it'd be easy to do.

Comment: You could get index of current toggle and then toggle only content of that index e.g. $(".stafflist-content:eq(" + toggleIndex + ")").SlideDown("slow);

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** have multiple DOM elements with the **same** ID!

Only the 1st element with that ID will get the event.

And nothing will wok as you want it to.

---

And you can use this `nextFind` plugin as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617389/561731) to do your selecting of the item you want to slide.

```
//to be used instead of prev/nextAll().eq(0);
(function ($) {
    var dirFind = function (selector, dir) {

        var elems = [];
        this.each(function (i, item) {
            while (item = item[dir]) {
                if (item.nodeType == 1) {
                    if ($(item).is(selector)) {
                        elems.push(item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return (this.pushStack(elems, dir, selector));
    }

    $.each({
        'prevFind': 'previousSibling',
        'nextFind': 'nextSibling'
    }, function (method, dir) {
        $.fn[method] = function (selector) {
            return dirFind.call(this, selector, dir);
        };
    });
}(jQuery));
//end of new prevall, nextall
```

So you can do:

```
$(this).nextFind(".stafflist-content").slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Changed my question slightly.

Comment: @Tenatious that was **not** a _slight_ change. if you have a new question, ask a new question... Do not change your OP.