# Finding a tag way up the hierarchy using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given the following html:

```html
<dt><span class="q-num">1</span>. What is one plus one?</dt>

<dd><input type="radio" value="a" name="1" required /> 4</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="b" name="1" required /> 7</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="c" name="1" required /> 2</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="d" name="1" required /> 8</dd>

<dt><span class="q-num">2</span>. What is two plus two?</dt>

<dd><input type="radio" value="a" name="2" required /> 4</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="b" name="2" required /> 7</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="c" name="2" required /> 2</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="d" name="2" required /> 8</dd>

<dt><span class="q-num">3</span>. What is three plus three?</dt>

<dd><input type="radio" value="a" name="3" required /> 4</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="b" name="3" required /> 7</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="c" name="3" required /> 2</dd>
<dd><input type="radio" value="d" name="3" required /> 6</dd>
```

I want to `alert()` the value of the nearest previous `span[class='q-num']` when any `input[type='radio']` is clicked. I've tried `closest()` but all I get is a blank alert..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`prevUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) is your friend:

```
$(this).parent().prevUntil('dt').last().prev().find('span[class="q-num"]').text();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPRBT/

---

If your posted markup is your real code, you can just use the `name` property of the clicked radio button:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Sj8/

---

A more efficient way would be to use [this custom traversal method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617226/is-there-a-fancier-way-to-get-a-previous-item-with-the-same-class):

```
$.each({
    'prevFind' : 'previousSibling',
    'nextFind' : 'nextSibling'
}, function(method, dir) {

    $.fn[method] = function (selector) {

        var elems = [];

        this.each(function(i, item) {
            while (item = item[dir]) {
                if (item.nodeType == 1) {
                    if ( $.find.matches(selector, [item]).length ) {
                        elems.push(item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return this.pushStack(elems, method, selector);
    };
});
```

which you can then use like this:

```
$(this.parentNode).prevFind('dt').find('.q-num').text()
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Sj8/1/

Comment: Your answer works perfectly. I added more markup. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: @rideTheWave - Not really. Is there any reason you're not using the value of `name` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert($(this).parent().prevAll('dt:first').find('span[class="q-num"]').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/PkMGN/